# CentOS + IPTables

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid, centos7

I am trying to setup a CentOS 7 server with Squid as a proxy server. The proxy server is strictly private and doesn't need to be available to anyone other than myself and other 2 servers, therefore I have decided to lock down all ports to the 3 IP addresses. I would also point out I have VNC access to the server in case my IP changes. Here are the IP table rules I am using to lock down the server (where 1.1.1.1 is just an example)...

```
#!/bin/bash
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
MYIP=1.1.1.1

#start and flush
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -P INPUT   DROP
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT

#HTTP traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MYIP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#SSH traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MYIP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#FTP traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MYIP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MYIP --dport 20000:20050 -j ACCEPT

#SQUID traffic
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MYIP --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT

#loopback
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
```

The problem is when I execute these rules, Squid stops working. It tries connecting but eventually returns a Squid error saying "Connection timeout". Even though all OUTPUT traffic is allowed, yum and wget also stop working so I am guessing it's failing to allow outbound traffic?

Can someone help me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/531571/126632

Comment: Problem solved! Should have asked this sooner and I wouldn't have wasted 4 hours messing around :/

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually Squid is still failing to connect :(

Comment: Are you using iptables-services (c7 package) or Firewalld?  If iptables-services, are you using iptables-save to overwrite /etc/sysconfig/iptables?  Did you check the status of iptables, firewalld or use journalctl to view the logs?  When your traffic stops working, do you still see your same rules in iptables -L -n -v?